# Is the intersection of a decreasing sequence of dense subspaces non trivial?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I'm an undergraduate student interested in the Invariant Subspace Problem. I write for clarity its statement:

> Given a Banach-space $X$ and a continuous linear map $T: X \to X$, is it true that there exists a closed invariant subspace $Y\subseteq X$ such that $Y\neq (0),Y \neq X$?

where *invariant* means that $TY\subseteq Y$.

I've read that it is in general false, but that are many important operators for which the statement is true. I've also read that the problem is open for many important Banach-spaces (perhaps reflexive Banach-spaces).
So I've tried to do something by myself.

My question is: can a Banach-space $X$ with the following property exist?

> **Property:** for every sequence $E_n\subseteq X$ of *dense linear subspaces* such that $E_{n+1}\subseteq E_n$ for all $n\geq 0$ we have $\bigcap_{n\geq 0}E_n\neq (0)$.

Then, if such property can be satisfied by some Banach-spaces, my question becomes:

> Does $\ell^2$ verify the property above?

Here's how I came to these questions. I'll consider only infinite dimensional Banach-spaces since there's nothing to say for finite dimensional ones.

Let's assume that the infinite dimensional Banach-space $X$ verify the property above and suppose that $T:X\to X$ does not admit a closed invariant subspace $Y$ except for $(0)$ and $X$. Let $x\neq 0$ an element of $X$. We define for $m\geq 0$

$$ S_m=\text{span}(T^nx)_{n\geq m} $$

It is clear that $S_m$ are invariant subspaces of $X$, and as a consequence $\overline{S_m}$ are invariant subspaces of $X$. If there exists a number $l\geq 1$ such that $S_0=(0)$ then $T^l x=0$ and so $S_1$ is a finite dimensional vector space, in particular $S_0=\text{span}(x,Tx,\dots, T^{l-1}x) $. As a consequence either $S_0$ is a non trivial closed invariant subspace of $X$ or $X=S_0$ is finite dimensional, contradicting that $X$ is infinite dimensional. So let's suppose that $S_m\neq (0)$ for all $m\geq 0$. Then $\overline{S_m}=X$ for all $m\geq 0$. Since $X$ verifies the property stated above, we know that
$$Z=\bigcap_{m\geq 0} S_m \neq (0)$$
Let $y\in Z$ with $y\neq 0$. Then there exist $n_0\geq 0$ and $\alpha_{i}$ with $0\leq i \leq n_0$ and $\alpha_i$ not all zero such that
$$ y=\alpha_0 x +\alpha_1 Tx + \dots +\alpha_{n_0} T^{n_0}x$$
Since $y\in S_{n_0+1}$ there exist $m_0\geq 0$ and $\beta_i$ with $0\leq i\leq m_0$ and $\beta_i$ not all zero such that
$$ y=\beta_0 T^{n_0+1}x+\beta_1 T^{n_0+2}x+\dots+ \beta_{m_0} T^{n_0+m_0+1}x $$
Equating the two expression obtained for $y$ we deduce that there exists a *non-null* polynomial $p(z)$ such that
$$ p(T)x=0$$
This implies that $S_0\neq (0)$ and it is finite dimensional, since we have $S_0=\text{span}(x,Tx,\dots, T^{n_0+m_0+1}x)$ and so either $S_0$ is a non-trivial closed invariant subspace or $S_0=X$ contradicting that $X$ is infinite dimensional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No infinite-dimensional separable Banach space has your property.  Namely, start with a dense sequence $s_n$.  There is a subsequence $s_{n_k}$ that is linearly independent and whose span is still dense (namely $s_{n_{k+1}}$ is the first member of the sequence that is not in the span of $s_{n_1}, \ldots, s_{n_k}$).  Take $S_m$ to be the span of $s_{n_k}$ for $k \ge m$.

EDIT: Oops: it's not at all clear that this construction makes the $S_m$ still dense.  OK, let's do things a bit differently.  Again, start with a dense sequence $s_n$.  We can make a new sequence $t_n$ that is still dense and is linearly independent: it suffices to make $t_n$ linearly independent of $t_1, \ldots, t_{n-1}$ with $\|t_n - s_n\| < 1/n$ say.  This can be done because the finite-dimensional subspace $\text{Span}(t_1, \ldots, t_{n-1})$
is closed and nowhere dense.  Now $E_m = \text{Span}(t_m, t_{m+1}, \ldots)$ is dense because it contains the dense set $\{t_m, t_{m+1}, \ldots\}$.

Comment: Thank you very much! In some sense I should have noticed that by myself watching carefully the last part of my proof (I think that you used notation S_m since it reminds mine for the other subsets). Thank you! I've really much to learn!

Comment: I'm really sorry to bother you, but I've a question. Why are the S_m still dense?

Comment: Ok, perfect! Thanks!